# How to insert widget in Newsletter?

Tags: magento-1.8, newsletter

I am extremely new to Mangento

I have created widget in Newsletter .
I can able to insert widget in Newsletter .
It inserts some code in

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="new_products" products_count="10" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_list.phtml"}}
```

if I preview this, it shows same code. I am not getting any real out put why.

Comment: didnt get what you are trying to explain. Could you give some more information on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Shyam I am new Mangento, I have got one task creating newsletter with 10 new products .It is completely developed by other developer . In Insert Widget button . I think he is already created Widget for listing out 10 new product. If I insert Widget it is creating some code . If I click and try to preview the product it don't shows any product it only shows .. that Widget  code ....

Answer (score 1):

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="new_products" products_count="10" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_list.phtml"}}
```

Paste that code in code view of editor, I think you are trying to put this code in visual view.

If its still not working trying to call that widget directly into any phtml file e.g `header.phtml` to make sure that your widget is working fine.

```
$filter = new Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter();
$widget = $filter->filter('{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="new_products" products_count="10" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_list.phtml"}}');
echo $widget;
```